# error while trying to run django application

Tags: python, django-models, runtime-error

I am trying to run my Django application but when I run this command `python manage.py runserver`  I am getting these lines more than 500 times how to solve this?

```
binomial.py first seen with mtime 1651731532.438017
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_identifier.py first seen with mtime 1651731507.214539
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py first seen with mtime 1530057078.0
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py first seen with mtime 1651731508.549226
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/_pcg64.cpython-36m-darwin.so first seen with mtime 1651731510.06907
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py first seen with mtime 1651731533.245426
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlparse/filters/reindent.py first seen with mtime 1651731531.25768
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py first seen with mtime 1651731532.410966
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/signal_handling.py first seen with mtime 1651731533.270655
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/decorators.py first seen with mtime 1651731510.077062
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py first seen with mtime 1651731502.130912
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/functools.py first seen with mtime 1530057075.0
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/_cm_listed.py first seen with mtime 1651731508.542586
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py first seen with mtime 1651731510.011403
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/unicodedata.cpython-36m-darwin.so first seen with mtime 1530057060.0
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_exceptions.py first seen with mtime 1651731509.993712
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/__init__.py first seen with mtime 1651731502.100659
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/_bounded_integers.cpython-36m-darwin.so first seen with mtime 1651731510.064277
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py first seen with mtime 1651731502.108338
File /Users/mansimishra/Documents/Deepfake-detection/Deepfake_detection_using_deep_learning/Django Application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/sbu.py first seen with mtime 1651731533.400134
```

I am getting these lines more than 500 times. How to solve this?

Comment: Can you share your LOGGING setting?

Comment: @lain Shelvington this error generated a log file should I share that?

Answer (score 1):

It's log from autoreload module when you set log level to `DEBUG`.
Try to suppress it by reduce log level or set log level for autoreload module

```
'django.utils.autoreload': {
    'level': 'INFO',
    # ...
}
```

For more information about setting log level in django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Comment: here is the logging settings

Comment: by making DUBUG true my application is not rendering HTML CSS  files ?

Answer (score 0):

By making extra debug configuration true in settings.py this error can be solved

```
if DEBUG == True:
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'log.django',
        },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django': {
                'handlers': ['console','file'],
                'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
            },
        },
    }
```